# Vuejs & Vuetify - Using Tinymce as a component in a dialog requires reloading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tinymce, vuetify.js

I am using tinymce as a component to create and edit articles

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/

I am also using vuetify and the component `v-dialog` and all my form is in this modal

However each time I change the instance of the tinymce component I have to reload the component by changing the `key` property

I think an example is more relevant

I have a web service in a development environment

https://service-dev.alexisgatuingt.fr/

id: test@stackoverflow.com

pass: p@ssw0rd!

To reproduce :

- Go to section "Articles"
- Open modal "Créer un articles"(The editor is located at the bottom)
- Close dialog
- And open the editing modal with the icon `mdi-pencil`

Finally there is no content in the editor, I have to click on "Relancer l'éditeur" to load content

Same for "Portfolio" section

You can create, edit, delete whatever you want, it's a development environment

Here is my code (simplify) :

modal.vue (The root component of the modal)

```
<template>
    <div :style="`z-index:${index} !important; display: inherit`">
        <!-- scroll bar = 15px -->
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent transition="dialog-top-transition" :hide-overlay="hideOverlay"
            :max-width="maxWidth" overlay-color="primary">
            <v-form v-model="formValidation" ref="form" lazy-validation enctype='multipart/form-data'
                :retain-focus="false">
                <slot name="content"></slot>
            </v-form>
        </v-dialog>
        <div style="display: inherit" @click="dialog = true">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

create.vue

```
<template>
    <modal title="Créer un article" description="Pour créer un article, renseigner les champs ci-dessous : "
        v-on:submit="submit" ref="modal" show-cancel label="Enregistrer">
        <slot></slot>
        <template v-slot:content>
            <v-btn @click="reload">Relancer l'éditeur</v-btn>
            <v-col cols="12" @focusin.stop>
                <editor id="create-article" :key="key" :api-key="apiKey" v-model="request.content"
                    :init="editorOptions"></editor>
            </v-col>
        </template>
    </modal>
</template>

<script>
import {editorOptions, apiKey} from "&/plugins/editor";
import {generateRandomKey} from "@/utils";

export default {
    name: "create",
    data() {
        return {
            key: '',
            apiKey,
            editorOptions,
            request: {
                content: '',
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
        },
        reload() {
            this.key = generateRandomKey();
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

edit.vue

```
<template>
    <modal title="Modifier l'article" description="Pour modifier cet article, renseigner les champs ci-dessous : "
        v-on:submit="submit" ref="modal" show-cancel label="Enregistrer">
        <slot></slot>
        <template v-slot:content>
            <v-btn @click="reload">Relancer l'éditeur</v-btn>
            <v-col cols="12" @focusin.stop>
                <editor :id="item.slug" :api-key="apiKey" :key="key" v-model="request.content"
                    :init="editorOptions"></editor>
            </v-col>
        </template>
    </modal>
</template>

<script>
import {editorOptions, apiKey} from "&/plugins/editor";
import {generateRandomKey} from "@/utils";

export default {
    name: "edit",
    props: {
        item: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            key: '',
            apiKey,
            editorOptions,
            request: {
                content: '',
            },
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.request.content = this.$props.item.content ?? '';
    },
    methods: {
        reload() {
            this.key = generateRandomKey();
        },
        submit() {

        },
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

editor.js

```
import store from '&/store';
import {mixin} from '@/store/mixin';
import Crud from "&/api/crud";

const MediaController = new Crud('media');

let imagesList = [];

MediaController.list({
    perPage: 999,
    search: 'image',
    page: 1,
}).then((r) => {
    r.data.forEach(e => imagesList.push({
        title: e?.oldName,
        value: e?.url
    }));
})

let method = mixin(store).methods;

const toolbar = ['searchreplace h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 bold italic underline strikethrough alignleft aligncenter alignright outdent indent  blockquote undo redo', 'removeformat subscript superscript code codesample hr bullist numlist link image charmap preview anchor pagebreak insertdatetime media table emoticons forecolor backcolor fullscreen'];

const plugins = ['advlist anchor autolink autosave code codesample directionality emoticons fullscreen hr image imagetools insertdatetime link lists media nonbreaking noneditable pagebreak paste preview print save searchreplace spellchecker tabfocus table template textpattern visualblocks visualchars wordcount'];

const editorOptions = {
    //selector: "textarea",
    height: 500,
    image_uploadtab: true,
    menubar: true,
    relative_urls: false,
    remove_script_host: false,
    convert_urls: true,
    images_upload_credentials: true,
    image_list: imagesList,
    images_upload_handler: (blobInfo, success, failure, progress) => {
        let form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
        form.append('type', "image/*");
        form.append('old_name', blobInfo.filename());
        MediaController.add(form).then((r) => {
            success(r.data.url);
        }).catch((e) => {
            method.showError(e);
            failure("Un problème est survenu");
        })
    },
    plugins,
    toolbar,
}

const apiKey = '#######################';

export {editorOptions, apiKey}
```

modal activator

```
<component is="edit"> // can be create
    <v-btn color="primary">
        Modifier
    </v-btn>
</component>
```

Update :

I also tried

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$watch(
            () => this.$refs.modal.dialog,
            (v) => v ? this.reload() : null,
        )
    });
},
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

After wrestling many hours with roughly the same problem, what worked for me was a combination of the following:

The outside component with the dialog containing the TincyMCE, set eager to True, and Retain-focus to False.

```
<v-dialog
    v-if="someCondition"
    v-model="openEditorModal"
    max-width="600px"
    scrollable
    :retain-focus="false"
    @click:outside="closeEditorModal"
    @keydown="closeOnKeydown"
    :eager="true"
/>
```

The component wrapping the TinyMCE conditionally shows its content with v-if:

```
<MceEditor
  v-if="showMce"
  :inline="true"
  :content="someObject.text
  @change="someObjectChange($event)"
></MceEditor>
```

Delay the TinyMCE creation and destroy it when the wrapping component unmounts:

```
  public mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.showMce = true;
      }, 3000);
    });
  }

  public beforeUnmount() {
    this.showMce = false;
  }
```

Ugly, but works.

Comment: saved potential time waste

Answer (score 0):

You should set only once (on mounting) different keys for each editor instance, then Vue will keep separate states for each instance of editor. For ex:

create.vue

```
mounted(){
  this.key = "editor-create"
}
```

edit.vue

```
mounted() {
  this.key = `editor-edit-${this.item.id}`
}
```

Or to simplify, set them directly in template:

```
<editor key="editor-create" ...></editor>
<editor :key="`editor-edit-${item.id}`" ...></editor>
```

Comment: No it does not work, I just updated the question with a code try, it doesn't work either

Comment: How do you get your `item` data? Is it defined when you assign it to this.request.content? could you console.log it before assigning?

Comment: For create component there is no props. But for edit Yes it's a props. `item` is the entity to update

Comment: ok, I think it may be a TinyMCE bug. see this report https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue/issues/230 . It has a similar behavior, and it may help you